# How to troubleshoot "DataMember Not Found" in ActiveReports

Tags: activereports

ActiveReports seems like a powerful flexible tool, but if you make a mistake anywhere, you get an exception "data member not found. please check your datasource and datamember properties".

There is no indication as to which datasource/datamember is at fault or what subreport the problem lies in, but Active Reports must know this!

The stack trace is no use, as the error is thrown after the report.run() method is invoked  from deep within code generated by Active Reports itself.

Does anybody have a solution other than commenting out one subreport after another and checking all fields in turn?

Comment: This error sucks, and I have never found a good way to find the affected subreport.

Answer (score 3):

I was getting the same error while trying to pass a raw dataset to a report as below:

...

`Dim rpt as New ActiveReport`

`With rpt`

`.DataSource = _data`

`.Run()`

`End With`

...

I specified a table in the dataset and the error went away.

...

`.DataSource = _data.Tables(0)`

...
`

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I don't know a way to immediately tell which subreport that error is coming from. Indeed, that error message should be improved when you're using subreports. I will report it to the ActiveReports development team.

Comment: ActiveReports team gave me case number 124157 to track the suggestiong of improving this error message in the future.

Comment: I just happen to run across this recently and the error message was improved by the ActiveReports Team to now include the subreport name.